# Database name with special character 'İ'

Tags: sql-server

Somebody create database with special characters name like 'PRİNCE' long time ago.So we can't change database name anymore.
Because of ' İ ' we can't call database from sys.databases.

```
select name
from dbo.sysdatabases
where name=cast('PRİNCE' as varchar(100)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

it works well

But there is a procedure which we using gives error
'Database 'PRİNCE' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.'

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50) -- database name 
Declare @strSQL nvarchar(max)

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
select name from MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases where (name not in('master','model','msdb','tempdb'))


OPEN c;  
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
begin
select @strSQL='use '+cast(@dbname as varchar(100))COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI+' Select  Db_name(DB_ID()) as Dbname from sys.database_files ;'
exec sp_executesql @strSQL
fetch next from c into @dbname
end
close c
deallocate c
```

Comment: So what is your question?  Do you want to rename the database?  Fix the stored procedure?  What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I change @dbname type to nvarchar and it worked! Thanks everyone...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `varchar` throughout and not `nvarchar`. The specific problem statement is this one:

```sql
select @strSQL='use '+cast(@dbname as varchar(100))COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI+' Select  Db_name(DB_ID()) as Dbname from sys.database_files ;'
```

I am guessing your database (`master` I assume) is not in the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI` so as soon as the assignment happens, the value is lost.

See, for example, the below:

```sql
DECLARE @Database sysname = N'USE ' + 'İ' COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI + ';';
SELECT @Database;
```

This returns `USE I;` *not* `USE İ;`. As object names are a `sysname` (a synonym of `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`) then make sure you use that data type through your code:

```sql
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @dbname sysname; -- database name 
DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(max);

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.databases --Don't use the old objects!
WHERE ([name] NOT IN(N'master',N'model',N'msdb',N'tempdb'));

OPEN c;  
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @strSQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'; SELECT DB_NAME(DB_ID()) AS DBName from sys.database_files;'; --Note QUOTENAME as well for proper quoting.
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @strSQL;
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname;
END;
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

*Ideally, I'd get rid of the `CURSOR` as well, but that's a completely different question.*